# Window AC unit in my house

Tags: electrical, air-conditioning

Okay, so i'm dying in a Texas Heat Wave and trying to figure out what to do. My Central AC unit went down and it's 1,500 to fix, and i don't have that.
I have an old AC Unit from my old house, and i was wondering if i could do this.

Picture: [image: House]

Black lines is the house itself, blue lines are the "entry room", which is a Bar that leads to the outside world, red is the garrage that connects to the Bar (but not the house).

There are no windows except sliding glass windows.

My idea is to put my AC unit in the doorway with the back facing into the Bar and hang a sheet over the AC so the hot air goes into the Bar, and the cool air goes into the house.

Will this work?

I also don't want to burn out my old ac unit.

Comment: What's the square footage of your house? How many feet across is the bar? Any distance between your window A/C's exhaust and the outdoors is going to hurt its efficiency, though your plan might still work. I would consider building a plywood frame to mount the window A/C in one of your sliding windows instead.

Comment: Can you push some of the A/C from the bar into the house? what is the cooling capacity of the window unit you plan to use. depending on the cooling load, 1 ton (12,000 BTU) unit will most likely only cool about 600 sq. ft. of floor space at 15 to 20 degrees below the outside temperature. If you are going to use this A/C unit then do as Robert Nubel , put it in a window and build some framing to keep it there.

Comment: Why can't you put the unit in a window, are they not large enough to fit it?

Answer (score 1):

This would be completely and fundamentally unworkable. Air conditioners *must* be installed so that heat is pumped to the outside of the structure.

The entry room would become excessively hot *and humid*. Remember, water vapor condensed on the cooling coils of the unit is conducted to the outside of the a/c unit where some is re-vaporized and some drips as liquid. This heat and humidity could damage the walls of the entry room.

The temperature in the entry room would be much higher than the ambient outdoor temperature and this would greatly reduce the efficiency of the refrigeration cycle of the a/c. And there would be heat flow through the wall of the entry room back into cooled space.

Answer (score 0):

Been there done that. I have spent $600 on central repairs this year , and the service guy ( who I trust) says the compressor is weak $ 2000 +). I put one room AC ( 5000 BTU)in our bedroom to keep it a few degrees cooler than the rest. I have a room AC in a hobby room and a third unit I just bought. The combined cost of 3 room AC was $400 . I think room AC is great if you vent it outside ; AND if your wife and the subdivision permits them .